# Need help fetching data from DB2

Tags: sql, db2

| S.no | emp_id | emp_name | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | John | Sales |
| 2 | 100 | John | Accounts |
| 3 | 200 | Mike | Sales |
| 4 | 300 | Mark | Sales |
| 5 | 300 | Mark | Accounts |
| 6 | 400 | Tom | Sales |

I need to pull all the emp_id who are linked ONLY to Sales Dept and ignore the ones that are in both Sales and Accounts. I am using DB2 z/os. Any suggestions would be helpful? Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL output should be 200 and 400 for the sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Please, don't post pictures. Edit the question with data example in a text form. What have you tried so far? Hint: use `NOT EXISTS` predicate.

Comment: I tried  below sql. Is there a better way to do performance wise? 

select emp_id from emp e where dept = 'Sales' and 
not exists ( select 1 from emp p where p.dept = 'Accounts' and p.emp_id = e.emp_id) with ur;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An anti-join will produce the result you want.

For example:

```
select s.*
from employee s
left join employee a on a.emp_id = s.emp_id and a.dept = 'Accounts'
where s.dept = 'Sales' and a.emp_id is null
```

For good performance you can try adding the index:

```
create index ix1 on employee (emp_id, dept);
```

Comment: Thank you. which has better performance.  left join or not exits considering both has index for respective columns?